# Re - structuring android project files in Android Studio

Tags: android, directory-structure

Since my application is growing more and more dense each day. I thought of re-structuring various files.

By re-structuring, I mean to add folders seperately for screen activites, another folder for dialog xmls, screen xmls, for custom adapters, etc. In other words, I need to segregate files according to their significance.

Currently, all my java files are listed in *src* folder (screen activities, custom adapters, business logic, etc.) and all the xmls (screens, custom list view design, custom dialogs, etc.) are present  in *layout* folder.

Is it feasible? What impact will it have on the existing project?

Comment: I do this (in Eclipse) to separate Java files. I separate Activities (normally 1 or as less as possible), Classes and Fragments. As easy as adding a folder under your src folder and move your files. Some methods have to be made public, though, and you'll need to add some imports.

Comment: I guess I want to do something similar as what you did. Can you please elaborate more?

Comment: I right click on the src folder, new folder (i.e.: classes). Then select my files (i.e.: all those beginning with CLS are classes) and move them there (drag and drop - Automatic refactoring does the magic for you). Then the Activities and Fragments using those methods must import this folder. And the methods which are shared inside the Classes must become public, or they won't be seen, because they are now not at the same level.

Answer (score 0):

Folders are synonymous with packages -- that's how the IDE interprets them.   So putting them in separate folders actually creates separate packages.  That's the downside, they won't have the same scope/permissions as if they were in the same package.

Comment: Some methods have to be made public, and you'll need to add some imports.

Answer (score 0):

**Packages in Java**

What you're talking about is most likely [packages](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/package/packages.html).

Packages makes structuring of bigger projects and navigating through it much easier.

However you can't without writing your own gradle extension put your XML files outside /res/ folder, but codewise, wrapping your classes in packages makes working in bigger codebase much easier

You define the package you class is in before defining the imports in following way:

```
package com.ruuhkis.test;

import android.content.Context;

class Test {
}
```

then the Test class is put in folder /src/com/ruuhkis/test/ folder to be found by the compiler

Comment: I don't want to put XMLs outside of *res/layout/*. The idea is to have folder structure inside the existing location, for instance, *res/layouts/customDialogs/*, *res/layouts/screens*, etc. I hope I made myself clear.